# In Perl, how can I pad an array with zeroes?

Tags: perl, pad

In Perl, how can I pad an array with zeroes? I know that I can get the length of the array, and then do a for loop with a push, but is there a more palatable way?

For example:

```
my @array = pad_with_zeroes("foo", "bar", "baz", 6);

# @array now eq ("foo", "bar", "baz", 0, 0, 0)
```

Is there anything in (for example) `List::Util` or a similar common module that can do this, as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my @array = ("foo", "bar", "baz");
my $total_length = 6;

push @array, (0) x ($total_length - @array);
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators):

> Binary "x" is the repetition operator. In scalar context or if the left operand is not enclosed in parentheses, it returns a string consisting of the left operand repeated the number of times specified by the right operand. In list context, if the left operand is enclosed in parentheses or is a list formed by qw/STRING/, it repeats the list. If the right operand is zero or negative, it returns an empty string or an empty list, depending on the context.

As a sub with the specified usage:

```
sub pad_with_zeroes { my $n = pop; return ( @_, (0) x ($n-@_) ) }
```

Comment: Don't you need parentheses around the subtraction? I do with Perl 5.18.0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, they should be there :)